# HoughCircle with trackbar opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, hough-transform

There are a few parameters in the `HoughCircle`function.
Is there a way to use the trackbars to change these parameters?
so that I would not need to run the program every time i want to change them.

Thank you.

using opencv 3.0.0 C++ on Ms VS 2013 on Win 8 laptop

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Create a window for trackbars
    namedWindow("Trackbar Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    //Create trackbar to change brightness
    int iSliderValue1 = 50;
    createTrackbar("Brightness", "Trackbar Window", &iSliderValue1, 100);

    //Create trackbar to change contrast
    int iSliderValue2 = 50;
    createTrackbar("Contrast", "Trackbar Window", &iSliderValue2, 100);

    int param1 = 10;
    createTrackbar("param1", "Trackbar Window", &param1, 300);

    int param2 = 10;
    createTrackbar("param2", "Trackbar Window", &param2, 300);

    cout << "All trackbars created" << endl;

    Mat src;

    VideoCapture capture;

    capture.open("movingBall.wmv");
    capture.read(src);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);

    cout << "Vidoe opened" << endl;

    if (!src.data) {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\topening image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::namedWindow("image1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cv::namedWindow("image2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true){

        capture.read(src);
        Mat dst;
        int iBrightness = iSliderValue1 - 50;
        double dContrast = iSliderValue2 / 50.0;
        src.convertTo(src, -1, dContrast, iBrightness);
        cout << "1" << endl;

        cv::imshow("image1", src);

    Mat src_gray2;
    cvtColor(src, src_gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(src_gray2, src_gray2, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    cout << "2" << endl;

    double dparam1 = param1 / 1.0;
    double dparam2 = param2 / 1.0;
    HoughCircles(src_gray2, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        2,   // accumulator resolution (size of the image / 2)
        5,  // minimum distance between two circles
        dparam1, // Canny high threshold
        dparam2, // minimum number of votes
        0, 0); // min and max radius
    cout << "3" << endl;
    std::cout << circles.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end of test" << std::endl;


    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
        // circle outline
        circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    }

    /*std::vector<cv::Vec3f>::
        const_iterator itc = circles.begin();

    while (itc != circles.end()) {

        cv::circle(src_gray2,
            cv::Point((*itc)[0], (*itc)[1]), // circle centre
            (*itc)[2],       // circle radius
            cv::Scalar(0,0,0), // color
            2);              // thickness

        ++itc;
    }*/

    cv::imshow("image2", src_gray2);
    cout << "5" << endl;
    cvWaitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have the `cout` expression to help me with locating the bug.
In the window, it is showing like this
[image]

And there is a problem with the `HoughCircle` function.

The code stops at number 2, and after like 10 seconds, it jump to 3 and loop over. I can't see what is the problem. The code itself(without talking about the detection part) is working fine before adding the trackbar. Or somehow the program just not responding.

What could be the problem

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem in houghCircle...but the parameters you selected gives a lot of circles which takes time to process this is the reason why it waits for 10 seconds before going to 3. try increasing the parameter 2, it will give faster results.

Here i have tried it using images in Python you can try to port from it...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:/Python34/images/2.jpg',0)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
def nothing(x):
    pass
cv2.createTrackbar('Param 1','image',0,100,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Param 2','image',0,100,nothing)
switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'image',0,1,nothing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    #To Get Parameter values from Trackbar Values
    para1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Param 1','image')
    para2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Param 2','image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'image')
    if s == 0:
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
    else:
    #For finding Hough Circles according to trackbar parameters
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,para1,para2,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        #For drawing Hough Circles
        for i in circles[0,:]:
           cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
           cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
           cv2.imshow('image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        img = cv2.imread('C:/Python34/images/2.jpg',0)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can use the above code as your refrence, firstly it creates a window and trackbars for switch and two parameter for hough circle.
then in the while loop para1 and para2 will store position of trackbars as value of canny parameter.
this is then used in cv2.HoughCircles function and the circles are drawn.
the image is again loaded so that every time you change parameter the output is given on fresh image to avoid confusing.

hope this might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed a library `math.h`, add `#include <math.h>` to the header.